# Unlimited TextFields with Form API

Tags: forms, 8

I'm creating a Block Plugin with a form. I'm able to create the standard form with various input field types. Like so.

```
    $form['text_field_1'] = array(
        '#type'          => 'textfield',
        '#title'         => $this->t('Entry 1'),
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['text_field_1_submit'],
        '#size'          => 60,
        '#maxlength'     => 10,
    );

    $form['text_field_2'] = array(
        '#type'          => 'textfield',
        '#title'         => $this->t('Entry 2'),
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['text_field_2_submit'],
        '#size'          => 60,
        '#maxlength'     => 10,
    );
```

This works but I can't anticipate how many entries the user may need, so I'd like users to be able to add multiple field entries in the same way that you can in a content type field.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a form API level feature, it's field/widget API.

For a custom form, you have to build it yourself with an add more button that uses #ajax to add more elements. A full code example would be too complicated for an answer, but you have to keep track of the count in $form_state, on pressing of the button increaes it, rebuild the form and then return the new elements.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x for more documentation, a quick tutorial that I found: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-ajax-forms-drupal-8/

Comment: Just checked, the drupal 8 example module has now an ajax add more example (commited on July 9).

Comment: are you talking about this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/examples because I'm having trouble finding the ajax add more example.

Comment: The ajax add more example in the examples module was put in the fapi_example module.  If you enable it, you should see it at: /examples/fapi-example/ajax-addmore

Answer (score 3):

Here's the example from the examples module found [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements the ajax demo form controller.
 *
 * This example demonstrates using ajax callbacks to add people's names to a
 * list of picnic attendees.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase
 */
class AjaxAddMore extends DemoBase {

  /**
   * Form with 'add more' and 'remove' buttons.
   *
   * This example shows a button to "add more" - add another textfield, and
   * the corresponding "remove" button.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('This example shows an add-more and a remove-last button.'),
    ];

    // Gather the number of names in the form already.
    $num_names = $form_state->get('num_names');
    // We have to ensure that there is at least one name field.
    if ($num_names === NULL) {
      $name_field = $form_state->set('num_names', 1);
      $num_names = 1;
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_names; $i++) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      ];
    }

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOne'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
    // If there is more than one name, add the remove button.
    if ($num_names > 1) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['remove_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Remove one'),
        '#submit' => ['::removeCallback'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_api_example_ajax_addmore';
  }

  /**
   * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
   *
   * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
   */
  public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $add_button = $name_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_names', $add_button);
    // Since our buildForm() method relies on the value of 'num_names' to
    // generate 'name' form elements, we have to tell the form to rebuild. If we
    // don't do this, the form builder will not call buildForm().
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
   *
   * Decrements the max counter and causes a form rebuild.
   */
  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    if ($name_field > 1) {
      $remove_button = $name_field - 1;
      $form_state->set('num_names', $remove_button);
    }
    // Since our buildForm() method relies on the value of 'num_names' to
    // generate 'name' form elements, we have to tell the form to rebuild. If we
    // don't do this, the form builder will not call buildForm().
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Final submit handler.
   *
   * Reports what values were finally set.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValue(['names_fieldset', 'name']);

    $output = $this->t('These people are coming to the picnic: @names', [
      '@names' => implode(', ', $values),
    ]
    );
    $this->messenger()->addMessage($output);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms) for Drupal 7 useful from Rapid Development Group. Their code below.

```
function custom_registration_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['storage']['participants'] =
    isset($form_state['storage']['participants']) ? $form_state['storage']['participants'] : 0;

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );

  $form['participants'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="participants">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if ($form_state['storage']['participants']) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['storage']['participants']; $i++) {
      $form['participants'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#tree' => TRUE,
      );

      $form['participants'][$i]['name'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
      );
    }
  }

  $form['add_participant'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Add A Participant'),
    '#href' => '',
    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'custom_registration_ajax_add_participant',
    'wrapper' => 'participants',
   ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Register'),
    '#type' => 'submit', 
  );

  $form_state['storage']['participants']++;

  return $form;
}



function custom_registration_ajax_add_participant($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['participants'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting to add multiple text field values in Drupal 8/9 theme settings (via - [`hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter/8.9.x) here is some code.

Based off a combination of:

- https://www.rapiddg.com/article/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms
- https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/3.x/modules/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 */
function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Some existing field set.
  $form['my_fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('My existing fieldset'),
    '#description' => t('My existing description'),
  ];
  // My item settings.
  $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('My item settings'),
    '#description' => t('My description'),
  ];
  // Gather the items list in the form state already.
  // Key 'myitems' must be same as array key.
  $form_state_values = $form_state->getValues();
  $myitems = isset($form_state_values['myitems']) ? $form_state_values['myitems'] : NULL;
  // If NULL, try theme settings.
  if ($myitems === NULL) {
    $myitems = theme_get_setting('myitems');
  }
  // We have to ensure that there is at least one item.
  if ($myitems === NULL) {
    $myitems = [''];
  }
  $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('My item list'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="myitems-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
  $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset']['myitems'] = [
    // Required for correct inputs to be generated.
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  ];
  foreach ($myitems as $key => $html_cache_headers_url) {
    $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset']['myitems'][$key] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('A single item'),
      '#description' => t('My single item description.'),
      // Key 'myitems' must be same as parent key.
      '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('myitems.' . $key),
    ];
  }
  $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset']['actions'] = [
    '#type' => 'actions',
  ];
  $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset']['actions']['add_item'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add one more'),
    '#submit' => ['__mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__add_one_item'],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '__mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'myitems-fieldset-wrapper',
    ],
  ];
  // If there is more than one item, add the remove button.
  if (count($myitems) > 1) {
    $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset']['actions']['remove_item'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove one'),
      '#submit' => ['__mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__remove_callback'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '__mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'myitems-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
  }
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
 *
 * Increments the amount of items and causes a rebuild.
 */
function __mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__add_one_item(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state_values = &$form_state->getValues();
  $paths_field = isset($form_state_values['myitems']) ? $form_state_values['myitems'] : [];
  $paths_field[] = '';
  $form_state_values['myitems'] = $paths_field;
  // Since our form() method relies on the value of 'myitems'
  // to generate 'item' form elements, we have to tell the form to rebuild.
  // If we don't do this, the form builder will not call buildForm().
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}

/**
 * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
 *
 * Selects and returns the fieldset with the paths in it.
 */
function __mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__add_more_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['my_fieldset']['myitem_settings']['myitems_fieldset'];
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
 *
 * Decrements the amount of items from the bottom and causes a form rebuild.
 */
function __mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter__remove_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state_values = &$form_state->getValues();
  $paths_field = isset($form_state_values['myitems']) ? $form_state_values['myitems'] : [];
  if ($paths_field > 1) {
    array_pop($paths_field);
    $form_state_values['myitems'] = $paths_field;
  }
  // Since our buildForm() method relies on the value of
  // 'myitems' to generate 'item' form elements, we have to
  // tell the form to rebuild. If we don't do this, the form builder will
  // not call buildForm().
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```